# javascript to asp.net communication

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a website that uses master pages. On the master page I have a sidebar div containing an Ajax accordion control that provides site navigation. When the user clicks a link from the accordion, I pass the index of the pane on the query string. Each webform inherits from a single base class. In the Page_Load event of the base class I check the query string for the active pane index and then set the Accordion.SelectedIndex property. This prevents the accordion control from resetting to pane 0 each time the user navigated to a different page.

The above works fine when navigating directly from the Accordion control. My problem is that it's also possible for the user to Navigate from a webform - they can click the 'Edit' hyperlink of a GridView which takes them to a page containing a DetailsView of the selected record. In this case I need to determine the index of "current" accordion pane so that I can set this on the page load event of the webform containing the details view.

I am able to trap the event of the accordion being selected with the following javascript:

```
function pageLoad() {
        var accordion = $find('<%= Accordion1.ClientID %>' + '_AccordionExtender');
        accordion.add_selectedIndexChanged(onACESelectedIndexChanged);
    }
    function onACESelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
        //alert(sender.get_SelectedIndex());
}
```

I need to store the "SelectedIndex" somewhere so that it can be read by the page_load event of the webform containing the details view.

Do I need to use cookies for this?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cookies and this works fine.

I did play around with the hidden fields but found this problematic as I couldn't always be sure which of the child webforms was loaded.

I have pasted the snippets of code I added to the page_load event of the base class I use for the child webforms, and the javascript for the click of the accordion control. This may be helpful to someone that had the same problem as me.

javascript

```
function pageLoad() {
        var accordion = $find('<%= Accordion1.ClientID %>' + '_AccordionExtender');
        accordion.add_selectedIndexChanged(onACESelectedIndexChanged);
    }
    function onACESelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {

        createCookie('acPane', sender.get_SelectedIndex(), 0)

    }
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
```

and now the c#

```
int acPane = 0;
        if (Request.Cookies["acPane"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie ckAcPane = Request.Cookies["acPane"];
            acPane = Convert.ToInt16(ckAcPane.Value);
        }

        if (acPane >= 0)
        {
            AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion ac;
            ac = (AjaxControlToolkit.Accordion)Master.FindControl("Accordion1");
            ac.SelectedIndex = acPane;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies is one, but you can use a HiddenField server-side control to store the value in the hidden element in client-side JavaScript, then access that hiddenfield on the server.  That's the easiest way, and works with both options.  You have to use the server-side control version so that you have access to the control on the server, otherwise, you have to use the Request.Form collection.

HTH.